# QUnit not running external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, qunit

I'm trying to adapt the tutorial [here](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_14.html#_building_a_javascript_unit_test_for_our_desired_functionality) to use QUnit v2.x, but it doesn't seem to be picking up the JavaScript file I want to test.

test.html

```
<div id="qunit"></div>
<div id="qunit-fixture">
  <form>
    <input name="text" />
    <div class="has-error">Error text</div>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="qunit.js"></script>
<script src="../list.js"></script>
<script>

    QUnit.test("errors should be hidden on keypress", function (assert) {
        $('input').trigger('keypress');
        assert.equal($('.has-error').is(':visible'), false);
    });

</script>
```

list.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('input').on('keypress', function () {
        $('.has-error').hide();
    });
});
```

The test fails with a result of true

The provided code in the tutorial works fine with QUnit 1.23

```
<script>

/*global $, test, equal */

test("errors should be hidden on keypress", function () {
    $('input').trigger('keypress');
    equal($('.has-error').is(':visible'), false);
});

test("errors not be hidden unless there is a keypress", function () {
    equal($('.has-error').is(':visible'), true);
});

</script>
```

Edit: Using QUnit v1.23 both versions of the tests work!

Comment: Are you sure all script paths in your *test.html* properly resolve? If the test fails then it seems like the code in *list.js* didn't run.

Comment: When putting the code in a script tag above the tests it still won't work. I'm not sure if that is working as intended though. The list.js file is accessible in the Web Inspector Resources.

Comment: I guess you are missing the HTML part from the tutorial then? Without that your selector `.has-error` will select nothing.

I created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhjparpv/#&togetherjs=PpGJ5xKVrA) and both tests are working fine.

Comment: @Daniel - I just excluded the HTML part from the question initially. I've added it now. Your fiddle is testing the wrong version of QUnit. You have 1.x tests, where I'm questioning the 2.x tests not working.

Answer (score 3):

So, this question has come up in [multiple other places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489182/calling-trigger-doesnt-always-fire-when-called-from-qunit) on SO. Essentially what happened is that QUnit 2 handles fixtures differently. Your code adds an event handler to the original HTML, but then QUnit kills that HTML and rebuilds it, thus removing your handler. The solution is to do the event binding **inside** your test, not on page load. Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dazy1msc/1/) to play with, but the code is below:

```
  function init() {
    $('.username').on('keypress', function() {
      console.log('hiding error!');
      $('.has-error').hide();
    });
  }

  QUnit.test("errors should be hidden on keypress", function(assert) {
    init();
    $('.username').trigger('keypress');
    assert.strictEqual($('.has-error').is(':visible'), false);
  });

  QUnit.test("errors not be hidden unless there is a keypress", function(assert) {
    init();
    assert.strictEqual($('.has-error').is(':visible'), true);
  });
```

Comment: So I have to wrap all my code in functions for QUnit? That seems very stupid

Comment: @Peregrinius I beg to differ. Your code should designed in components that can be unit and (unit-) integration tested independently from each other. Testing becomes much more explicit and more maintainable than just relying upon and testing global state.
The code above might look slightly nicer if you use `beforeEach` hooks.

Comment: @Peregrinius You don't _have_ to write all your code in functions, but if you don't then you're setting yourself up for a mess. Besides that point, QUnit is doing what is correct by resetting that HTML before each test. That's industry standard for HTML fixtures.